# Leetcode House robber

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I was trying [House Robber](https://leetcode.com/problems/house-robber/) problem(dp problem) on leet code.
This solution from one of the user GYX looks simple and elegant.

```
   int rob(vector<int>& num) {
   int n = num.size();
        if (n==0) return 0;
        vector<int> result(n+1,0);
        result[1] = num[0];
        for (int i=2;i<=n;i++){
            result[i] = max(result[i-1],result[i-2]+num[i-1]);
        }
        return result[n];
   }
```

But I just could not get my head around the logic. Please help me with the logic and also how to approach problems like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose I store the amount in kth house in `house[k]`.

Suppose now I store the maximum amount of money possible to loot from the first k houses(and first k only) in `max[k]`.

Now consider no houses, so `max[0]=0`

Now considering only first house, `max[1]`=amount in house 1

Now considering first 2 houses,

`max[2]`={either `max[1]`(implies we chose to loot house 1) or (amount in house 2 + maximum amount that I had looted until the house located 2 places before my current house)}=`{max(max[1],house[2]+max[0])}`

Similarly for first 3 houses, `max[3]=max(max[2],house[3]+max[1])`

Observing this trend, it can be formulated that `max[k]=max(max[k-1],house[k]+max[k-2])`. This value is calculated till in the end when there are no more houses, we get the maximum amount that can be looted from these first n houses.

DP problems strike the head only when you have had some practice and familiarity before, and this always helps.

Answer (score 6):

Basically the answer is `f(n) = max( f(n-1), f(n-2) + arr[n] )` and you are asking why.

Let's suppose this array `arr = [9,1,7,9]` and `f(n)` is the function.

**When the array is only `[9]`**, your max `f(0)` will be `arr[0]`.

**When the array is `[9,1]`**, your max `f(1)` is `max(arr[0], arr[1])`.

**When the array is `[9,1,7]`**, if you select `7`, you **can't** select `1` therefore `f(n-2) + arr[n]`. However, if you don't select `7`, you max `f(2)` will be same as `f(1)` which is `f(n-1)`.

**When the array is `[9,1,7,9]`**, you need to drop both 1 & 7 and choose 9, 9. `f(n) = max( f(n-1), f(n-2)+arr[n] )` equation satisfies this case.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this simple recursive code. Visulizing a problem solved in DP is hard at first glance. You should always work your way up to that from a low performant recursive code first. Here is a different version of the code:

```
p = [0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 8, 2]
def R(i):
    if i == 1 or i == 2:
        return i
    else:
        return max(p[i] + R(i - 2), R(i - 1))

print(R(11))
```

This is also easily memoizable if you want to bring the efficiency up.