# Dynamic programming with memoization on the rob house problem

Tags: c, dynamic-programming, memoization, discrete-mathematics

This is my problem I'm working on:
" You are a professional robber planning to rob houses along a street. The houses are numbered
0, 1, 2, ..., and you my assume that the number of houses is at most 10000. Each house has a certain amount of money stashed. The only constraint stopping you from robbing each of them is that adjacent houses have their security systems connected and they will automatically contact the police if two adjacent houses are broken into on the same night.

Given a list of non-negative integers representing the amount of money of each house, determine the
maximum amount of money you can rob tonight without alerting the police."

I have to make it work by using dynamic programming with memoization by modifying `rob( )`, `rob_rec()`, and introduce a new function that can be called by `rob( )`. I can't change `main( )`. Function `rob( )` and another function `rob_rec( )` solves the problem using dynamic programming with memoization as follows. They should have time complexity O(numHouses).

I would like to achieve an output of this:

```
Score = 4
Check to verify solution:
 Score = 4
 Money = 1 2 3 1
 House = 1 0 1 0
Score = 12
Check to verify solution:
 Score = 12
 Money = 2 7 9 3 1
 House = 1 0 1 0 1
Score = 19
Check to verify solution:
 Score = 19
 Money = 10 7 3 9 1
 House = 1 0 0 1 0
Score = 605
Check to verify solution:
 Score = 605
 Money = 72 7 54 23 29 56 32 21 20 64 68 86 70 95 62 59 94 9 63 15
 House = 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0
```

Below is my current code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define HOUSE_SIZE 20

int rob(int* money, int* house, int numHouses);

/*  Utility functions */
void clear_houses(int * house, int length); /* Clears array house[] */
void check_houses(int * house, int * money, int length);  /* Checks if houses are valid */
void random_fill(int * money, int length); /* Randomly fill array */
void display_array(int* a, int length);

int main()
{
    int money1[4] = {1, 2, 3, 1};
    int money2[5] = {2, 7, 9, 3, 1};
    int money3[5] = {10, 7, 3, 9, 1};
    int money4[HOUSE_SIZE];
    random_fill(money4, HOUSE_SIZE); /* Fill money4[ ] */

    int house[HOUSE_SIZE];

    clear_houses(house, 4);
    printf("Score = %d\n", rob(money1, house, 4));
    check_houses(house, money1, 4);

    clear_houses(house, 5);
    printf("Score = %d\n", rob(money2, house, 5));
    check_houses(house, money2, 5);

    clear_houses(house, 5);
    printf("Score = %d\n", rob(money3, house, 5));
    check_houses(house, money3, 5);

    clear_houses(house, HOUSE_SIZE);
    printf("Score = %d\n", rob(money4, house, HOUSE_SIZE));
    check_houses(house, money4, HOUSE_SIZE);
}

int rob(int* money, int* house, int numHouses)
{
    if (numHouses == 0) return 0;
    if (numHouses == 1) {
        house[0] = 1;
        return money[0];
    }

    int* maxMoney = (int*)malloc(numHouses * sizeof(int));
    maxMoney[0] = money[0];
    maxMoney[1] = (money[0] > money[1]) ? money[0] : money[1];

    for (int i = 2; i < numHouses; i++) {
        int robCurrentHouse = maxMoney[i - 2] + money[i];
        int skipCurrentHouse = maxMoney[i - 1];

        if (robCurrentHouse >= skipCurrentHouse) {
            house[i] = 1; // Mark the house as robbed
            maxMoney[i] = robCurrentHouse;
        } else {
            house[i] = 0; // Mark the house as skipped
            maxMoney[i] = skipCurrentHouse;
        }
    }

    int result = maxMoney[numHouses - 1];
    free(maxMoney);
    return result;
}

void display_array(int* a, int length)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < length; k++) {
        printf("%3d", a[k]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void random_fill(int * money, int length)
{
    int state = 11;
    for (int k = 0; k < length; k++) {
        state = (53 * state + 71) % 97;
        money[k] = state;
    }
}

void check_houses(int * house, int * money, int length)
{
    int check_score = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k < length; k++) {
        if (house[k] == 1) check_score += money[k];
    }

    printf("Check to verify solution:\n");
    printf("   Score = %d\n", check_score);
    printf("   Money = ");
    display_array(money, length);
    printf("   House = ");
    display_array(house, length);
    printf("\n");
}

void clear_houses(int * house, int length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        house[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble understanding how to update the house array so that it's filled correctly and the `rob()` function returns the correct value. Can anyone help me?

This was my output:

```
Score = 4
Check to verify solution:
   Score = 3
   Money =   1  2  3  1
   House =   0  0  1  0

Score = 12
Check to verify solution:
   Score = 10
   Money =   2  7  9  3  1
   House =   0  0  1  0  1

Score = 19
Check to verify solution:
   Score = 12
   Money =  10  7  3  9  1
   House =   0  0  1  1  0

Score = 605
Check to verify solution:
   Score = 741
   Money =  72  7 54 23 29 56 32 21 20 64 68 86 70 95 62 59 94  9 63 15
   House =   0  0  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  0
```

Comment: Finding an optimal solution is certainly not an O(n) problem. Probably even verifying a given solution can't be done in O(n) time. Where is this problem from and why do you think it's a dynamic programming/memoization exercise that can be solved in O(n) time?

Comment: This is a problem that was given in a discrete math book I'm studying from and supposedly it can be solved using dynamic programming and memoization.

Comment: O(n) seems overly ambitious to me. You might be able to do it in O(nlogn) time with divide and conquer type approach. For example, split the array into two, then the boundary can only have three possible values 00, 01, and 10. Then calculate the maximum for each half, using the same trick.

Comment: I may be wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39541824/leetcode-house-robber

Comment: I think the issue here is that you can't use the formula s_n = max(s_{n-1}, house[i] + s_{n-2}) to find an actual optimal selection from the array. It only gives the maximum you can steal. The original question only asks for this amount, not an example array that achieves it. You can maybe do that the way I suggested earlier, but probably not in O(n) time.

Comment: @SimonGoater in fact you can. Let `f(n) = max(f(n-1), f(n-2) + arr[n])` be the maximum **amount** of profit up to the `n`th house, as before. Let `h(n)`, the function returning the list of houses, be defined as: `h(n) = h(n-1) if f(n-1) >= f(n-1) + arr[n] else h(n-2) + [n]`.  Here `h(n-2) + [n]` denotes concatenation of the list returned by `h(n-2)` with the list containing only the element `n`. If the concatenation is done in-place (mutating the list), and `f(x)` is memoised, then the algorithm is `O(n)` time.

Comment: @DillonDavis You're right that the algorithm you suggest does complete in O(n) time, but it gives the wrong answer (assuming you meant if f(n-1) >= f(n-2) + arr[n]). There must be some weird logical fallacy in going from the sum total to getting an optimal selection. Try it, and let me know if I'm wrong. I get the obviously wrong 01101111111101011010 or 10101111111101011010 with sums of 748 and 813 respectively doing this, though the sum only calculation is verified as correct at 605 for the 20 house example.

Comment: @SimonGoater I have just tried it, and it gives me the correct answer.  Perhaps you have an off-by-one error, or maybe are using `n` instead of `arr[n]` somewhere?

Comment: @DillonDavis I think maybe I misunderstood the proposed solution. I'll take another looks at it later...